# Can we define charge as a measure of something or in terms of interactions?

Tags: mass, charge, definition, measurements

like we define mass to be the measure of inertia or how much a body can interact with space time or with Higgs field, there must be a way to define charge as a measure or in form of some interaction. Is it just some short of property?

Comment: Have you learned Coulomb’s Law? A full century before the discovery of protons and electrons, the charge of an object was understood based on how much electrostatic attraction or repulsion it caused. Classical electromagnetism does not require elementary particles or the Standard Model.

Comment: Yeah, I know Coulomb's Law. I just want to know how deeply we have understood the term charge. I want upgrade because I am not satisfied by that definition of it being just some short of property of an object. There must be a reason why such property is exists. Like something has mass because it interacts with Higgs field, there must be some reason or something that is causing particles to have charge.

Comment: In quantum field theory, charge is understood as the [coupling constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_constant) between the photon field and any other quantum field (such as an electron field). The underlying concept is local U(1) gauge invariance.

Answer (score 1):

Charge in the mainstream physics theories at the moment emerges in bulk matter from the basic standard model of particle physics, where charge is a number identified with the [particles in the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) . It is unique to each particle, 0, +/-1 or +/-1/3 **axiomatically**, the identification dependent on experiments.

So, no, in the present theories of mainstream physics it takes part in interactions but is not the result of interactions to be able to define it in another way.